# file and path listing separator :

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, find, command

I need to to list out a folder structure for a folder/cd/dvd, but I need the path and the filename to be displayed. I can do this using find command:

```
find /path*
```

but instead of the usual / as a separator I need the separator to be :

So when I use find on a folder I get the following output:

```
2D/Resource/2011 Brand-Guidelines/1664/Logos/1664/Small/K1664-CMYK-Background-Small.ai
2D/Resource/2011 Brand-Guidelines/1664/Logos/1664/Small/K1664-PMS-Background-Simple-Small.ai
2D/Resource/2011 Brand-Guidelines/1664/Logos/1664/Small/K1664-PMS-Background-Small.ai
2D/Resource/2011 Brand-Guidelines/1664/Logos/1664/Small/K1664-PMS-Simple-Small.ai
```

But I need it to display the output like so:

```
2D:Resource:2011 Brand-Guidelines:1664:Logos:1664:Small:K1664-CMYK-Background-Small.ai
2D:Resource:2011 Brand-Guidelines:1664:Logos:1664:Small:K1664-PMS-Background-Simple-Small.ai
2D:Resource:2011 Brand-Guidelines:1664:Logos:1664:Small:K1664-PMS-Background-Small.ai
2D:Resource:2011 Brand-Guidelines:1664:Logos:1664:Small:K1664-PMS-Simple-Small.ai
```

This is because often users will use slash's in the file names when they are not supposed to.

Comment: It shouldn't even be *possible* to create a file with a `/` in its name under Linux.

Comment: The files were created in OS X and Apple users just can't understand that you should not use those symbols and many others in file names. So as much as I try to educate there will always be someone that does this.

Comment: Even in OS X, I think trying to use `/` in a file or folder name really creates a file system entry that uses `:` in place of `/`. The Finder retains the `/`-version in its metadata, but the file system itself prohibits `/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a suggestion:

```
find /path* | sed 's/\//:/g'
```

or

```
find /path* | tr '/' ':'
```

Both of them can meet your requirement.

Comment: What do you mean by "it can't work"? `find | sed` and `find | tr` both work here, without a temporary file.

Comment: @tripleee I just try, It works too,  I will change the answer. Thank you to mention that.

Comment: That worked find perfectly. Thank you very much